# SSRS report export to excel and give a sheet name issue

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working with a local report in report viewer from VS2010.

The RDLC has more than one control on it and I am setting the PageBreakAtEnd propery to True in order to force a soft page break
which also results in a 2nd Excel sheet being produced when the user exports to Excel.

However, the sheets in excel are called 'Sheet 1' and 'Sheet 2'.

How can I give sheet name. so i search google and found a link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets.aspx
from this link i came to know that it is possible. there is property called pagename. i am designing report 
from VS2010 but i could not found pagename property. so anyone can tell me where is the pagename property exist.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page Name property is introduced with 2008 R2. Are you working on SQL2008R2?
Below is a blog post walking through steps:
[Page Name SSRS 2008R2](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/762/ssrs-r2-naming-excel-worksheet-tabs)

Comment: +1 This answer seems like the correct course of action. However, it did not work for me, but that seems to be because of [specific versions not working together](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/16fdbede-9bd1-46a9-ae76-31fd67aa5a53/pagename-property-not-working-for-excel-2010?forum=sqlreportingservices) (Excel 2013 + SSRS 2012 for me).

Answer (score 3):

There are many tutorial on how to change the PageName field to set the tab name for excel export, but they all tend to miss a very important setting for the SSRS project you are working on:

Solution Explorer –> Right click the project name and select Properties –> TargetServerVersion.

Change it to “SQL Server 2008 R2″.

Without this setting, pageName field you set will not show up on the excel export as the tab name. Hope this help someone like me dealing with an old project.

Comment: This answer solved my issue. The project was set to SQL Server 2008 not SQL Server 2008 +